# Animating UINavigationBar

Tags: objective-c, iphone, core-animation, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I want to slide the right button and the title in and out (instead of having things just appear and disappear). How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can (sort of) animate the title by using a custom view for UINavigationItem's `titleView` property and doing the animation yourself. As for the right button, you can't animate it without *completely* rewriting UINavigationBar (not recommended).

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using property setter syntax, i.e. self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO, use the method setter to specify an animated parameter:

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```

This should achieve what you want.